# How to combine 2 images into 1

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm trying to take a cropped photo and stick it on a texture map of a coffee mug where it says "Place Logos here" and apply that map to a 3d dae model. My initial attempt doesn't do anything. I'm not sure to draw croppedImage onto my mapImage

```
let croppedImage = NSImage.init(cgImage: croppedCGImage, size:NSSize.init(width: cropWidth, height: cropHeight))

//texture map
let mapImage = NSImage.init(named: "coffee_c.jpg")
let mapImageData = mapImage?.tiffRepresentation
let bMap:NSBitmapImageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: mapImageData!)!

NSGraphicsContext.init(bitmapImageRep: bMap)
mapImage?.draw(in: CGRect(x: cropX, y: cropY, width: cropWidth, height: cropHeight))
let newImage = NSGraphicsContext.current
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create an NSImage by drawing, you can use `lockFocus`/`unlockFocus` (typed in Safari):

```
let newImage = NSImage(size: .../* probably the size of your original/background */)
newImage.lockFocus()
// draw the first image, draw something on top of that, etc.
newImage.unlockFocus()
// ... you can now draw newImage wherever you want
```

This is covered in the [Cocoa Drawing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Images/Images.html)

If you need your image to be sensitive to different screen resolutions, consider `NSImage(size: NSSize, flipped: Bool, drawingHandler: @escaping (NSRect) -> Bool)`, which uses the code block to lazily create the image in the actual rendering context.